# How does Pyramid's add_static_view work?

Tags: python, web-applications, pyramid

How does add_static_view(name, path) in Pyramid work?

From the docstring:

> "The `name` argument is a string representing an application-relative
>   local URL prefix. It may alternately be a full URL.
>   The `path` argument is the path on disk where the static files
>   reside. This can be an absolute path, a package-relative path,
>   or an asset specification."

Somehow I have got the impression that this description is not
very accurate.

If I add some code along the lines of

```
config.add_static_view("static", "/path/to/resource/on/filesystem")
```

and I visit

```
http://localhost:PORT/static/logo.png
```

I see the logo.png given
that it can be found in

```
/path/to/resource/on/filesystem/
```

Now, if I have some code like the following

```
config.add_static_view("http://myfilehoster.com/images", "myproject:images")
```

the description that "the `path` argument is the path on disk where
the static files reside" does not seem accurate anymore because the actual
files reside on the disk of myfilehoster.
It seems to me that I am merely registering some kind of identifier
(myproject:images) that I can use within my program code to reference
the "real" location "http://myfilehoster.com/images".
E.g.

```
request.static_url("myproject:images/logo.png")
```

would be resolved
to "http://myfilehoster.com/images/logo.png".

So is the documentation inaccurate here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing something. In the [narrative documentation on static assets](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html#serving-static-assets) it states:

> Instead of representing a URL prefix, the `name` argument of a call to `add_static_view()` can alternately be a *URL*. Each of examples we’ve seen so far have shown usage of the `name` argument as a URL prefix. However, when `name` is a *URL*, static assets can be served from an external webserver. In this mode, the `name` is used as the URL prefix when generating a URL using `pyramid.request.Request.static_url()`.

In the [API documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_static_view) similar wording is used:

> When `add_static_view` is called with a `name` argument that represents a URL prefix, as it is above, subsequent calls to `pyramid.request.Request.static_url()` with paths that start with the `path` argument passed to `add_static_view` will generate a URL something like `http://<Pyramid app URL>/images/logo.png`, which will cause the `logo.png` file in the images subdirectory of the `mypackage` package to be served.

Using a URL switches the behaviour of `add_static_view` altogether and the `path` argument is interpreted as a symbolic path only for the `.static_url()` method. That latter detail is perhaps not described as explicitly in the documentation, you could file an issue in the [pyramid issue tracker](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues) if you feel strongly about that.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies it for me. I guess I will probably propose a change to the documentation which otherwise has been very good so far.

Comment: I think this convinced me using it everywhere now.