# Web fonts always return 404 from static path

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm having trouble with a static view, it is configured to serve files from the 'assets' folder on the server, and works fine for the following '/assets/img/hdr.png','/assets/style/default.css' however when trying to serve a web font it always returns 404 not found (despite the fact I have triple checked the file is in the correct locaiton ('/assets/font.woff')

Is there something additional I need to configure to allow non img/css files to be served?

`config.add_static_view(name='assets', path='assets')`

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what library your using but try and force the Content-Type to "application/font-woff" (not tested)

Comment: This questinos seams to serve your needings. [stackoverflow add_static_view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689841/how-does-pyramids-add-static-view-work

Answer (score 2):

The `path` argument should be an [asset specification](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/glossary.html#term-asset-specification). This means you should prefix the `path` with the name of your package `mypkg:assets`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant to the OP, but I hit the same problem.

The reason was that `setup.py install` simply didn't copy the font files, and the solution was to include all the font extensions in the `MANIFEST.in` file.